# How do I import only the number and separate between 'n' and 'p'?

Tags: import

I have a file like this:

```
 primario =  980 pione n, en=   0.10229 GeV
 primario =  980 pione n, en=   0.10506 GeV
 primario =  980 pione p, en=   0.65135 GeV
 primario =  980 pione p, en=   0.44895 GeV
 primario =  980 pione p, en=   3.15166 GeV
 primario =  980 pione n, en=   1.03541 GeV
 primario =  989 pione n, en=   1.14979 GeV
 primario =  990 pione p, en=   0.72569 GeV
 primario =  992 pione p, en=   5.80965 GeV
 primario =  993 pione p, en=   0.24496 GeV
 primario =  993 pione n, en=   0.39453 GeV
 primario =  993 pione n, en=   1.07869 GeV
 primario =  997 pione p, en=   0.11673 GeV
```

I have to import only the number after `en` and separate the result into two lists of `p` and `n`. Using something like `"FieldSeparators" -> {"=", ",", "primario", "en", "pione", "=", "GeV"}` I should be able to import only the numbers and the strings `p` and `n`.

Now my problem is: I am left with a list like this

```
{{262, "p", 2.58277}, {272, "p", 1.17827}, {275, "p", 2.35279}, {281, "p", 0.17932}, {281, "p", 0.74644}, {292, "p", 1.44102}, {292, "p",0.41372}, {292, "p", 5.4164}, {297, "p", 0.38317}, {297, "p", 0.50133}, {297, "n", 0.91764}, {307, "p", 0.08304}, {307, "p", 0.16932}, {307, "n", 2.11982}, {307, "p", 2.78014}}
```

how do I separate the list into two lists containing only the last numbers? This lists, then, should be separated into a `p` list and a `n` list? The final lists should be something like this:

p list: `{2.58277,1.17827,...}` n list: `{0.91764,...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use **GroupBy**:

```
a = {{262, "p", 2.58277}, {272, "p", 1.17827}, {275, "p", 
2.35279}, {281, "p", 0.17932}, {281, "p", 0.74644}, {292, "p", 
1.44102}, {292, "p", 0.41372}, {292, "p", 5.4164}, {297, "p", 
0.38317}, {297, "p", 0.50133}, {297, "n", 0.91764}, {307, "p", 
0.08304}, {307, "p", 0.16932}, {307, "n", 2.11982}, {307, "p", 
2.78014}};
assoc = GroupBy[a, Extract[2] -> Last]
```

This groups the lists based on the second element of those lists, and the values it groups together is the last element of these lists. 
Then the list p and the list n can be found using:

```
assoc["p"]
assoc["n"]
```

---

Alternatively, it can be done using **Select**:

```
plist = Select[a,EqualTo["p"]@*Extract[2]][[All,3]]
nlist = Select[a,EqualTo["n"]@*Extract[2]][[All,3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here are two simple options:

Using `Cases`

```
a = {{262, "p", 2.58277}, {272, "p", 1.17827}, {275, "p", 
    2.35279}, {281, "p", 0.17932}, {281, "p", 0.74644}, {292, "p", 
    1.44102}, {292, "p", 0.41372}, {292, "p", 5.4164}, {297, "p", 
    0.38317}, {297, "p", 0.50133}, {297, "n", 0.91764}, {307, "p", 
    0.08304}, {307, "p", 0.16932}, {307, "n", 2.11982}, {307, "p", 
    2.78014}};

Cases[a, {_, "p", i_} :> i]
```

> {2.58277, 1.17827, 2.35279, 0.17932, 0.74644, 1.44102, 0.41372,
>   5.4164, 0.38317, 0.50133, 0.08304, 0.16932, 2.78014}

```
Cases[a, {_, "n", i_} :> i]
```

> {0.91764, 2.11982}

Or using `Select`

```
Select[a, #[[2]] == "p" &][[All, 3]]
Select[a, #[[2]] == "n" &][[All, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `Sow` and `Reap`.  For example:

```
a = {{262, "p", 2.58277}, {272, "p", 1.17827}, {275, "p", 
    2.35279}, {281, "p", 0.17932}, {281, "p", 0.74644}, {292, "p", 
    1.44102}, {292, "p", 0.41372}, {292, "p", 5.4164}, {297, "p", 
    0.38317}, {297, "p", 0.50133}, {297, "n", 0.91764}, {307, "p", 
    0.08304}, {307, "p", 0.16932}, {307, "n", 2.11982}, {307, "p", 
    2.78014}};

res = Reap[Sow[#1[[3]], #1[[2]]] & /@ a, _, Rule][[2]]

/* {"p" -> {2.58277, 1.17827, 2.35279, 0.17932, 0.74644, 1.44102, 
   0.41372, 5.4164, 0.38317, 0.50133, 0.08304, 0.16932, 2.78014}, 
 "n" -> {0.91764, 2.11982}} */
```

And then use `ReplaceAll` to give the individual lists, e.g.

```
"n" /. res

/* {0.91764, 2.11982} */
```